# How do I pass a variable size data structure back to the controller from my view in MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a view based on a list, intending to allow users to edit one or more members of the list, at the same time, on the same page.

I'd like to collect all of the edited (or, failing that, all) fields into a data-structure (a list or array?) to pass back to the controller, who will then update my database, as appropriate, for each element in the list.

Is there an MVC .NET shorthand for building this type of view, or do I have to manually collect this data on the client side (say, with Javascript) before passing it back to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). Also checkout the [following post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) to better understand the expected wire format for lists and dictionaries used by the default model binder in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few elements to this problem:

1. Creating a view that will allow you to [add/edit multiple items](http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/2008/12/saving-dynamically-added-list-items-using-jquery-and-aspnet-mvc/).
2. Sending that information back to the controller. Reading up on [Modelbinding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) will solve the second part.